# Is a Unicursal Graph an Euler Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Euler graph is defined as:

> If some closed walk in a graph contains all the edges of the graph
>   then the walk is called an Euler line and the graph is called an Euler
>   graph

Whereas a Unicursal Graph does an **open walk**. So can we say a unicursal graph is an Euler graph?

Answer (score 1):

In the terminology of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), *unicursal* and *eulerian* both refer to graphs admitting closed walks, and graphs that admit open walks are called *traversable* or *semi-eulerian*. So I'll avoid those terms in my answer.

Any graph that admits a closed walk also admits an open walk, because a closed walk is just an open walk with coinciding endpoints.

Vice versa, this is not always the case. Not any graph that admits an open walk also admits a closed walk. A simple example for this is a graph with only one edge.

Comment: If a closed walk is also an open walk, can it be safe to say that a Unicursal graph is an Euler graph?

Comment: No, it is not safe to say, using the definition of "Euler graph" and "Unicursal graph" you provided. The last paragraph of my answer explains why.